# How to create a basic setup.py script when one of the modules is named parser?

Tags: python, setuptools

It seems from [here](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issue/48/attributeerror-_dep_map) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577975/python-attributeerror-dep-map), that setuptools does not work properly when a project has a module named `parser` in it.  I am trying to write a basic setup script for this project: https://github.com/karlmoritz/bolinas .  This is not my repository and I want to avoid making any changes to this code (or if it is not possible to make no changes, then only making minimal changes).

As you can see, there is a package called `parser` that conflicts with the default python installation.  This is my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name = "Bolinas",
    version = "0.1",
    packages = find_packages(),
    scripts = ['bolinas.py', 'config.py'],
)
```

When I run it, I get the same errors as in the links I provided above.

Is there anything I can do to make this work without renaming the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These guys really have top level packages called "common", "config" and "parser"? No sane person would install this (or would later rue the day). Its not a problem with setup.py at all. Its a problem with a package that overrides standard system modules like "parser".

As stands, bolinas is not architected to be installable. To do so, its modules should all be moved under a package called 'bolinas' so that the base level namespace isn't littered with a bunch of vaguely named modules.

Comment: This answer perfectly sums up what I was thinking when I looked at that repo. Unfortunately, packaging up `bolinas` into a distribution that plays nice with others requires quite a bit more work than just writing a `setup.py`.

Comment: @LukasGraf - its not too bad. They have top level scripts that need to be changed to `import bolinas.whatever`, and there are some data files that you need to figure out how to package, but its a more useful product when its done.

Comment: I guess that's a danger of using academic software.  Scientists aren't software architects.

Comment: I'm just venting because the internal packages at my company are written in this same horrible way.